# Why is MSTest trying to parse my parameters out of order?

Tags: c#, mstest, .net-4.7.2

Why is MSTest trying to parse values from my `DataRow` out of order?

Here's my code:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("foo-string", 13)]
[DataRow("foo-string", 50)]
public void Test(string foo, int bar)
{
  ...
}
```

And my error:

```
Message: There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Int32. The value 'foo-string' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.
```

Debugging the test confirms that the code inside my test method is never hit. The error happens by the test runner before it can enter the method.

Why isn't MSTest parsing my DataRow values in order, and correctly assigning them to the parameters for my test method as expected?

--

Even more strange, this just started happening, seemingly randomly, after making some code changes elsewhere in the solution that shouldn't impact this test at all.

I'm using VS2017, and my solution is .NET 4.7.2.

`MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework` nuget packages are installed at version `3.02`.

Comment: You didn't make a change to a SQL statement, and start returning columns in a different order, did you?

Comment: @AnnL.: The data comes from the `DataRowAttribute` not from SQL.  It's right there in the question.

Comment: Right, what Ben said.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, I misread it. I thought the DataRow was coming from a DataTable that was defined elsewhere.

Comment: Well my first thing to check would be to stash those changes that you think are unrelated and see if it still behaves this way.

Comment: Try to downgrade both packages to version 3.0.0 or even 2.2.10. They recenly made some changes in how parameters are used in test method. Maybe this is a bug in a framework.